# How can I intercept a call from PouchDB to CouchDB, using .net

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I am learning PouchDB with CouchDB and trying to wrap my head around intercepting documents to the couchdb server and performing an action on it wether it be creating other documents, updating the user table, etc.

On the server the json document will be treated through a business layer before it is submitted to the couchdb server, preferably in .net.

Is this possible? If not, is there a way to do so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the server side, you can listen to the `_changes` feed from CouchDB ([docs here](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/database/changes.html)) and react whenever a document is added, modified, or deleted. This could be useful for reporting/messaging/aggregation/etc.

Alternatively, if you want to do some schema validation on the documents before they are accepted, then you should look into adding a design doc with a `validate_doc_update` field ([docs here](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Document_Update_Validation)).

Comment: Hi! I was just watching your video yesterday :)..

So basically there is no event to capture incoming changes before it is submitted to the database. It must be submitted first and querying for changes. Correct?